# Force bluetooth 2.1 to use bluetooth 2.0 protocol?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a problem using the SPP Bluetooth in Android 3.2.
I made a program (and also tried some free applications from Android Market) to connect to bluetooth devices. I have several devices that use bluetooth 2.1 and 2.0.
The program could connect to the device with bluetooth 2.0 but not to 2.1. I think it is caused by more secure protocol in bluetooth 2.1.
Is there any way to force the program to use bluetooth 2.0 to connect to the 2.1 device?

Comment: What APIs are you using in your app to connect ? Can you post a code snippet.. also any error logs

Comment: I uses the same example as in http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

While connecting to Bluetooth 2.1, the application could not open a Bluetooth socket, that#s why, I want to use Bluetooth 2.0 protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth 2.1 adds Secure Simple Pairing, which is a major security upgrade.  While it is possible for new devices to support the legacy mode, many devices will not allow connection via the old 2.0 mode.  You would have to look a the specs on the particular devices to know what types of BT security they support.

Comment: I am using Acer Tablet with Android 3.2.